# problem running several command over SSH with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to run several command over SSH with JSch.The different command works fine but I have a problem: it looks like the system restart from the root folder after any cmd, if I try to read in another folder, simply I can't because I will read again the root folder. Consider I'am enough new in this.

This is my method that menage the command (it is composed by parts founded here on stackOverflow):

```
public String ask (String command) throws SftpException, IOException, JSchException {
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
         try
         {

        Channel  channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();

        while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
        {
           outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
           readByte = commandOutput.read();
        }

        channel.disconnect();
     }
     catch(IOException ioX)
     {
        System.out.println("PROBLEMI NEL CHANNEL DI SESSIONE");
        return null;
     }
     catch(JSchException jschX)
     {
        System.out.println("ALTRI PROBLEMI");
        return null;
     }
     System.out.println(outputBuffer.toString());
     return outputBuffer.toString();
}
```

No error/exception.
I am tryng to execute 2 simply conseguent cmd like: "cd " and "dir".

So, as suggest by Martin Prikryl, "concatenate" the cmd like "cd nameFolder && ls". For my test porpuse it is enough, if someone else have some more ideas...

Comment: 1. What are the commands you are trying to run? 2. What problem are you facing?

Comment: An easy: 
-cd <folder name>  -
ls/dir

Comment: And the error/exception?

Comment: You should edit the information into your question, not post them in comments.

Comment: No error/Exception. Simply the second cmd return to me the files inside the root folder where i was before the cd command. In single way any command works fine.

Comment: Though why, don't you simply do `ls <foldername>`?

Comment: Martin, that could be a nice workaround, but the problem could come again in different context. Anyway thank you

Comment: OK. I've posted a link to the *general solution* twice already and you never ever reacted.

Comment: I don't understand the link you shared me. I hoped in a simple way, that's why I asked. I will need to read more documentation to transfer your example from python to java. I repeat myself: I'am new in this context.

Comment: There's nothing Python-specific in my answer. Just use one command like  `cd aaaa && ls`.

Comment: Anyway i will try the example suggested there and I will let you know/edit my question

Comment: Did you try to read an error stream before opening input stream?

Comment: No, I did not... But i will.

Comment: @mate00 There's no point trying to read error stream. There won't be any error. The problem is clear, the `ls` command is executed in a different shell than the `cd`, so `ls` succeeds (no errors), but reads a different directory than OP wanted.